# ExtJS 4 PagingToolbar throwing dom errors on subsequent page loads

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc, gridpanel

I'm fairly new to ExtJS, but have been able to get a GridPanel working with an associated paging toolbar. Everything works fine, until I close the popped up window and open another one. On the subsequent window loads, I get a "me.dom is undefined" error. If I remove the paging toolbar, everything works fine. I'm using version 4.0.7.

Thanks in advance.

Store definition:

```
Ext.define('VIMS.store.TOs',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model:'VIMS.model.TO',
    requires: 'VIMS.model.TO',
    sorter:{property:'StartDate', direction:'DESC'},
    buffered: true,
    pageSize: 10,

    listeners:{
    beforeload: function(store,options) {
        if(options.params && options.params.id){
            store.getProxy().extraParams.id = options.params.id;
        } 
    }, 
},
});
```

GridPanel definition:

```
Ext.define('VIMS.view.TaskOrderList' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.taskorderlist',
    title : 'Task Orders',
    store: 'TOs',
    requires:'Ext.toolbar.Paging',
    height:'100%',
    columnLines:true,
/* removed this code ---------------------------------------
    dockedItems :[{
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                store: 'TOs',   // same store GridPanel is using
                pageSize:10,
                dock: 'bottom',
                displayInfo: false,}],
-------------------------------------------- */             
initComponent: function() {

    this.columns = [

        {header: 'Description',  dataIndex: 'Description',  flex: 1},
        . . . 
        {header: 'Id',  dataIndex: 'TaskOrderId',  hidden:true},
    ];

     // added from here ---------------------------------
      var PagingBar = new Ext.PagingToolbar({
        pageSize: 10,
        store: 'TOs',
        displayInfo: true,

        });
        this.bbar = PagingBar;

    // to here ---------------------------------------

    this.callParent(arguments);
}

});
```

To open the window, from my controller I use the following:

```
    var view = Ext.widget('contractedit');
    view.modal = true;
    view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
```

The close is handled via the following:

```
    closeMe: function(button) {
        var win    = button.up('window');
        win.close();
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra trailing comma that maybe getting in the way:

```
displayInfo: false,
```

also how r u managing the window?

Comment: Dmitry,
Removing the trailing comma didn't change the behavior. I'm managing the windows using a controller. I've added the code above from the controller showing how I open and close the window.

Comment: so window contains a form, and not the grid, right? So wheres is the connection between window and the grid?

Comment: Yes, window contains a form that contains a tab panel that contains multiple grids each with paging toolbars. If I remove the paging toolbars from the grids, everything works fine (except no paging of course).

Comment: do the grids share stores or other components? would it be possible for you to post the source into a jsfiddle with data loaded from a simple JSON array?

Comment: They don't share stores or other components. Let me see what I can do with jsfiddle. Thanks for your help on this Dmitry.

Comment: Okay - I managed to find a solution that works, but I'm not sure why. I commented the OP with inline comments. I now have a working pagingToolBar for my grids.